# Calculate the value of dt in reverse

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Firstly, I gave the value of $dt=0.00006$ and the range of $0<=t<=0.08$, and then calculated the maximum value of cond, as shown in the following code:

```
dt = 0.00006;
il = Function[t, 
   1.0909090909090908` + 
    1.0279241950771227` E^(-267.92850868181444` t) - 
    2.118833285986214` E^(-186.61694586364015` t)];
cond = Abs[-1/2 dt (il'[t + dt] - il'[t])];
Maximize[cond, 0 <= t <= 0.08, t]
{0.00001757589750421772`, {t -> 0.00441792334183185`}}
```

Here, I use the maximum value of *cond* calculated above, $0.0000175757589750421772$, as the upper bound of the code *cond* below, and then calculate $dt$ in reverse, as shown in the following code:

```
il = Function[t, 
   1.0909090909090908` + 
    1.0279241950771227` E^(-267.92850868181444` t) - 
    2.118833285986214` E^(-186.61694586364015` t)];
cond = Abs[-1/2 dt (il'[t + dt] - il'[t])] <= 0.00001757589750421772;
RegionPlot[{cond}, {t, 0, 0.08}, {dt, 0, 0.0001}, 
 FrameLabel -> {t, dt}]
NMaximize[dt, {cond, 0 <= t <= 0.08, 0 <= dt <= 0.0001}, {t, dt}, 
 MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

[image]

From the operation results shown in the picture, it can be seen that the calculated $dt\ne0.00006$ at this time. I would like to ask how to reverse calculate the value of $dt$ and obtain the result of $0.00006$?

**Update my questions**

This time, I transformed the inequality into an equation and calculated it using **NMinimize**. For *il*, the correct result $dt=0.00006$ was successfully calculated and obtained. On this basis, I added *vc*, and $0.0021307474843557$ is also the maximum value of *vc* that I calculated using $dt=0.00006$. Similarly, I reverse calculate the $dt$ corresponding to the maximum value of *vc*. The code is as follows：

```
il = Function[t, 
   1.0909090909090908` + 
    1.0279241950771227` E^(-267.92850868181444` t) - 
    2.118833285986214` E^(-186.61694586364015` t)];
vc = Function[t, 
   23.999999999999996` + 
    55.082039324993595` E^(-267.92850868181444` t) - 
    79.08203932499359` E^(-186.61694586364015` t)];
cond1unequal = 
  Abs[-1/2 dt (il'[t + dt] - il'[t])] <= 0.000017575897504217294;
cond2unequal = 
  Abs[-1/2 dt (vc'[t + dt] - vc'[t])] <= 0.0021307474843843557;
cond1equal = 
  Abs[-1/2 dt (il'[t + dt] - il'[t])] == 0.000017575897504217294;
cond2equal = 
  Abs[-1/2 dt (vc'[t + dt] - vc'[t])] == 0.0021307474843843557;
RegionPlot[{cond1unequal, cond2unequal}, {t, 0, 0.08}, {dt, 0, 
  0.0001}, FrameLabel -> {t, dt}]
NMinimize[dt, {cond1equal, 0 <= t <= 0.08, 0 <= dt <= 0.0001}, {t, 
  dt}, MaxIterations -> 1000]
NMinimize[dt, {cond2equal, 0 <= t <= 0.08, 0 <= dt <= 0.0001}, {t, 
  dt}, MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

[image]

From the operation results shown in the picture, it can be seen that for *vc* the calculated $dt\ne0.00006$ at this time. How can I obtain the correct result for *vc* $dt=0.00006$ too ( *vc* corresponds to the yellow curve in the image, and it can be roughly seen from the curve that $dt=0.00006$ is obtained at the boundary value, which is $t->0$)?

Comment: Try reversing the cond inequality and minimizing dt. As in “smallest value dt for which the desired condition fails”. Obviously you can use equality rather than an inequality in this setting.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Sir, based on your method, I have successfully calculated the value of $dt=0.00006$ for *il*. But when I calculated *vc* in the same way, I couldn't get the correct result of $dt=0.00006$. I have updated the details in the original problem.

Comment: Given the magnitude of exponents, you might require precision higher than machine precision. I am surprised it worked for the il computation.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you, sir! After setting the $WorkingPrecision->10$, I calculated the $dt$ corresponding to *vc* and obtained a result close to $0.00006$.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked.